# Переделать форму wpcf7-form

Tags: php, wordpress, form

День добрый, есть скопированный сайт и в нем нужно переделать форму, чтобы сообщения приходили на любой ящик, который я укажу.

Сам код формы:

```html
form action="/#wpcf7-f101-o2" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="101" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="5.1.1" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="ru_RU" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f101-o2" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="g-recaptcha-response" value="" />
</div>
<p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap named"><input type="text" name="named" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Ваше имя" /></span><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap phone"><input type="tel" name="phone" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-tel phone-mask" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__" /></span><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email"><input type="email" name="email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="E-mail" /></span><br />
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" /></p>
<div class="contact-form__checkbox">
<div class="contact-form__checkbox-text">Согласен с <a href="/privacy-policy/"> политикой конфиденциальности</a></div>
<p>  <span></span>
</div>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, переделать под этот скрипт `

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
/* Устанавливаем e-mail Кому и от Кого будут приходить письма */    
    $to = "ваша почта"; // Здесь нужно написать e-mail, куда будут приходить письма
    $from = "admin@site.ru"; // Здесь нужно написать e-mail, от кого будут приходить письма

/* Указываем переменные, в которые будет записываться информация с формы */
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = "Форма отправки сообщений с сайта ";//Фиксированная тема письма

/* Проверка правильного написания e-mail адреса */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("<br /> Е-mail адрес не существует");
}

/* Переменная, которая будет отправлена на почту со значениями, вводимых в поля */
$mail_to_myemail = "Здравствуйте! 
Было отправлено сообщение с сайта ! 
Имя: $first_name 
Фамилия: $city
E-mail: $email 
Номер телефона: $phone 
Текст сообщения: $message 
Чтобы ответить на письмо, создайте новое сообщение, скопируйте электронный адрес и вставьте в поле Кому.";  

$headers = "From: $from \r\n";

/* Отправка сообщения, с помощью функции mail() */
    mail($to, $subject, $mail_to_myemail, $headers . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    echo "Ваши данные получены. Спасибо Вам, " . $first_name . ", мы скоро свяжемся с Вами.";
    echo "<br /><br /><a href='site.ru'>Вернуться на сайт.</a>";
}
?>
```

`

Comment: Твой скрипт мало того, что дырявый и нерабочий на нормальном хостинге, но и вообще не имеет никакого отношения с CF7. Просто настраивай формы в плагине.

Comment: В писании написано же "есть СКОПИРОВАННЫЙ сайт" причем тут формы в плагине ?

Comment: @Apofemka На данном сайте не приветствуется выполнение заданий за другого человека. Вон - я даже нахватал минусов за ответ, за то, что Вам помог. Но решил помочь, так как Вы новый участник сообщества. А это просто хейтеры. )

Comment: @Apofemka если ты не понимаешь зачем этот плагин и советов что нужно жделать, то это совершенно другая проблема. Не техническая.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```php
<?php
?>
<form action="help5.php" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<div style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="101" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="5.1.1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="ru_RU" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f101-o2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="g-recaptcha-response" value="" />
</div>
<p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap named"><input type="text" name="named" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Ваше имя" /></span><br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap phone"><input type="tel" name="phone" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-tel phone-mask" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__" /></span></br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email"><input type="email" name="email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="E-mail" /></span><br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap named"><input type="date" name="date" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Дата отправки письма" /></span><br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap named"><input type="text" name="city" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Город отправки" /></span><br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap named"><textarea type="text" name="message" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Текст сообщения" /></textarea></span><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" formmethod="post" value="Отправить" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" /></p>
<div class="contact-form__checkbox">
    <div class="contact-form__checkbox-text">Согласен с <a href="/privacy-policy/"> политикой конфиденциальности</a></div>
    <p>  <span></span>
</div>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form>
```

help5.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    /* Устанавливаем e-mail Кому и от Кого будут приходить письма */
    $from = "admin@site.ru"; // Здесь нужно написать e-mail, от кого будут приходить письма

    /* Указываем переменные, в которые будет записываться информация с формы */
    $first_name = $_POST['named'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = "Форма отправки сообщений с сайта ";//Фиксированная тема письма

    $to = $email; // Здесь нужно написать e-mail, куда будут приходить письма

    /* Проверка правильного написания e-mail адреса */
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
    {
        show_error("<br /> Е-mail адрес не существует");
    }

    /* Переменная, которая будет отправлена на почту со значениями, вводимых в поля */
    $mail_to_myemail = "Здравствуйте! 
Было отправлено сообщение с сайта ! 
Имя: $first_name 
Город: $city
E-mail: $email 
Номер телефона: $phone 
Текст сообщения: $message 
Чтобы ответить на письмо, создайте новое сообщение, скопируйте электронный адрес и вставьте в поле Кому.";

    print_r($mail_to_myemail);
    $headers = "From: $from \r\n";

    /* Отправка сообщения, с помощью функции mail() */
    mail($to, $subject, $mail_to_myemail, $headers . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    echo "Ваши данные получены. Спасибо Вам, " . $first_name . ", мы скоро свяжемся с Вами.";
    echo "<br /><br /><a href='site.ru'>Вернуться на сайт.</a>";
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: разместил данную форму. спасибо, но сообщения не приходят на почту

Comment: @Apofemka Сообщения приходят. Проверил. Но так как отправляются с сервера - попадают в спам. Хотите, чтобы этого не происходило - Вам надо настроить службу `mail` на своей рабочей машине. Внёс корректив по тексту сообщения - можете обновить. Добавил скрин как приходит письмо.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь, форму исправил, но, к сожалению, ваш вариант так и не заработал, пришлось вовсе менять скрипт)